# AWS Cognito returns new ID after clearing app data in Android

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I am using AWS Cognito for device authentication and synchronizations. I have enabled unauthenticated users as well.

The app works perfectly fine I am able to keep track of the user data using the ID. But when the user clears the App Data from settings and makes a request for a Cognito Identity, a new identity is generated.

**How can I make sure that only one identity is assigned to one device?** I'm not an Android expert. Please share any relevant documentation link. I tried but didn't find anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Cognito Android SDK saves the identity id in shared preferences, so it is wiped if the data is cleared. If you're using unauthenticated identities, when data is cleared, the only way to keep an identity is to track it externally (i.e. sustain it in a file).

If you were using authenticated, simply passing the same provider token would guarantee the same id. If you're using Cognito Sync as well, I would highly recommend you use authenticated instead of unauth. That would allow the user to easily get the same id and data on multiple devices, and would prevent a lost identity id inherently.

There's logically no way for Cognito to know that two unauthenticated ids belong to the same person.

Comment: Also when the user logs out of the account, Cognito generates a new id.

Comment: That's expected behavior - an identity cannot go from authenticated back to unauthenticated. If you were to log back in and re add the provider token, you would get back the original authenticated ID.